# "An assembly with the same simple name " error when trying to generate fakes in VB 2013

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2013, com-interop, microsoft-fakes

I am trying to generate a fake on a custom DLL in VS 2013 and get this message:

"An assembly with the same simple name '...' has already been imported. Try removing one of the references or sign them to enable side-by-side."

I've gone over the code with a fine comb and can't see where the extra reference is. The assembly references is a COM assembly and I am referencing the correct Interop version, so I don't think this is the issue. Anyone else seen this?